# Arm custom u-boot reversing

Tags: ida, disassembly, firmware, arm

I'm trying to reverse a custom u-boot that implements cryptography for the Kernel at runtime (the Kernel at rest is encrypted also in a flash). I can probably ask the IoT vendor to provide the modified code of u-boot, but I want to learn something from this experience.

Some info I gathered:

- [SOC Data Sheet](https://support.hkvstar.com/file/Hi3519_Datasheet.pdf) (with memory layouts)
- Ram start at 0x8000_0000 (2 GB)
- BOOTROM at 0x0400_0000 (64K)
- BOOTRAM at 0x0401_0000 (64K)
- Remapable area from 0x0000_0000 to 0x03FF_FFFF (64 Mb)
- *Strings* on the *u-boot.bin* file return: `bootcmd=kload 0x82000000; bootm 0x82000000`
- The CPU is Arm Cortex A7 (the SOC have also an A17 but is not the "default" one)

Steps I'm doing to load the binary in IDA:
[image: Step 1 IDA]

IDA asked me for the disassembly memory organizations; I tried a couple of things without success. I think this is the part where I messed up something, and later I can find proper addresses when I try to rebuild the Interrupt Vector Table to start defining functions later.

[image: Step 2 IDA]

Which address I should choose in this case based on the information I have?

An example, if I chose to use `0x8000_0000` as a loading address and redefine some variables to *double word* (any Interrupt vector table entry is a double word), this is what I get:

[image: IDA example]

I get something unusable (I can't jump at those addresses); I need to understand how to set up IDA in the early stages.

Any help, especially with some theory, is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The reset vector location is the address right after `0xDEADBEEF` (not shown in your snippet).

It is the function that the first instruction's relative branch is branching to.

Tell IDA to load the segment at that address (`0x8080xxxx`).

Comment: I didn't update the post, but I found that `0x8080_0000` (looking at DATA ref after an auto analysis). I found a forum where someone analyzed the code, of the custom u-boot, under a developing point of view and `0x8080_0000` is referenced as the loading address, so I guess it's confirmed. A user on Reddit (blessthe28) suggested turning all the `0xEXXX` into code since those are unconditional ARM codes, and effectively I got some `LD` to `PC` register in the order suggested by the user. 
[actual IDA status](https://imgur.com/a/uf8jsya)